# How to bind image and text together in the same column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to bind the image and text together in the same column. I managed to bind the text part but failed to bind the image part. This is what I've done so far:

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn x:Name="TimeColumn" Header="Time" Width="80">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
              <MultiBinding>
                <!--<PUT IMAGE>-->
                <Binding Path="Time"/>
              </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
          </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

This is my expected result:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot bind both text and image into the TextBlock so you need to try something like:

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn x:Name="TimeColumn" Header="Time" Width="80">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image /> <!-- YOU NEED TO POINT THIS TO YOUR IMAGE -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: I would add a padding to the image, too because otherwise the image will stick directly to the text. `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Padding="0,0,10,0"/> <!-- YOU NEED TO POINT THIS TO YOUR IMAGE -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>
          </StackPanel>`